# How to reun a docker container without removing it first?

Tags: docker

I want to run a redis server locally with docker. I pull the image by

```
docker pull redis
```

Then I used this command to bring up a docker version of redis server

```
docker run --name test -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

For my test, I brought this instance down. I used

```
docker ps
```

to confirm the instance was down.

Now I want to start it up again, and I get this

> docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name
>   "/test" is already in use by container
>   "29cae620afcc10c62f4704801178d71a041f4828c9f683b56a658affa9a01de5".
>   You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that
>   name.

Is there any faster to restart it other than funning `docker rm test` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `docker ps -a` and identify the container id, or name ("test" in your example)

then run `docker start <ID>` or `docker start test` in your case